# Return a string with \n replaced with newlines

Tags: python, dictionary, return, newline, traceback

I'm relatively new to Python so excuse me if it's a simple fix.

I'm returning a dict from an api, and in case of an error along they way to avoid a server crash i instead return a different dict with the fields:

```
try:
    all_pods = settings.client.list(Pod, namespace=namespace)
    all_pods_organized = organize_pod(all_pods, 'one_namespace')
except Exception:
    errorid = uuid.uuid4()
    all_pods_organized = {
        'success' : False,
        'details' : {
            'errorID' : errorid,
            'traceback' : traceback.format_exc()
        }
    }
return all_pods_organized
```

That last 'traceback' field is the cause of my current issue.

The function `traceback.format_exc()` returns a string. It works fine when I print it alone, but when it's returned in the dict, the newlines disappear and I'm left with a single line string with \n all throughout.

Here I voluntarily caused an error to demonstrate the answer since i'm only looking to make

I understand that \n are the symbol for newlines but I'm simply wondering if there is a way that i could return this dict and instead of having the traceback field filled with :

```
"traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File 
\"C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Documents\\GitHub\\infra-management-api\\app\\api\\pods.py\", line 27, 
in get_all_pods\n    all_pods_organized = organize_pod(all_pods, 'one_namespace')\n                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n  
File \"C:\\Users\\Jacob\\Documents\\GitHub\\infra-management-api\\app\\api\\pods.py\", line 93, in organize_pod\n    
for pod in Pod['items']:\n               ~~~^^^^^^^^^\nTypeError: 
type 'Pod' is not subscriptable\n"
```

Having this in the traceback field:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\GitHub\infra-management-api\app\api\pods.py", line 27, in get_all_pods
all_pods_organized = organize_pod(all_pods, 'one_namespace')
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\GitHub\infra-management-api\app\api\pods.py", line 93, in organize_pod
for pod in Pod['items']:
           ~~~^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: type 'Pod' is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code that is causing the error, also use the `{}` button in the editor to format both code and errors

Comment: could you share your function & the code that calls the dictionary?

Comment: based on `File "C:\Users\Jacob\Documents\GitHub\infra-management-api\app\api\pods.py", line 93, in organize_pod\n for pod in Pod['items']:\n ~~~^^^^^^^^^\nTypeError: type 'Pod' is not subscriptable\n"` you should try printing the `Pod` variable to see what it is